# destructure data after fetch it cause error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I'm trying to learn testing with React, so I've written some basic async code so when I did fetch the data then try to destructure it, I got an error telling me that: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'movie' of undefined" despite it's being fetching and displaying on the browser.

Here is the component :

```
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

const Test = () => {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState({});
  const url = 'https://yts.lt/api/v2/movie_details.json?movie_id=10';
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url);
        const json = await res.json();
        // error is here, TypeError: Cannot read property 'movie' of undefined
        const {
          data: { movie }
        } = json;

        setMovie(movie);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return movie ? (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <h1 data-testid="movie-title" key={movie.id}>
        {movie.title}
      </h1>
    </div>
  ) : null;
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: If you have valid keys and values in JSON, then you should try `const { data } = json` and then `const { movie } = data`

Comment: it's valid and gets rendered in the browser, 
I think the error wasn't specific, 
there was an error in the test file for the component which is somehow causing that error, I fixed it and the error gone from the component itself. 
thank you.